# Per-record classifying dates by another table's names for those date ranges

Tags: python, django, django-models

Bit of a long-winded title, but essentially I've got Models for projects, with various foreign key sub-models for aspects of it.
One related table is a Model where specifically named Date periods are defined, ie. a start and end date are provided and that date is then named by the user, and linked to a set project. It's easiest to think of it as maybe quarters based off that specific project's start date, but it's not always strictly quarters so I can't use conventional 'built-in' date tools. The user has to be able to define assymetrical reporting periods.
Every project also has an Events model linked to it for specific occasions/happenings on the project, each with a date that I then need to stratify into these Project_Periods. Since it falls in a range of dates I can't just call up the usual foreign-key relations.
The absolute easiest would be just to force the user to select a Project_Period for each Project_Event they add - but there's a lot of events and I want it to be set automatically without a user being able to mismatch it.

I've thought of saving a date/calendar table for every project once the Project_Period is saved or altered - a model under Project_Peroid that then defines days inside every Project_period object - but I'm assuming that's inefficient/space wasting.

I could have it run through a For-Loop either when saving the Project_Events or modifying Project_Periods, to classify each event and assign it a Project_Period foreign-key but I'm assuming that's also wasteful or inefficient.
Similarly on the View when calling it up I could have it run through each event object to then run through a for-loop of every Period_event linked to that project with something like Period_Event.objects.filter(date__range=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-31"]) where the dates are set by the Project_Period that's being looked up, but that might also be wasteful.

Other techniques I've seen like Annotate seem more for grouping basic on already clearly defined relationships, rather than fuzzy 'within a range, within an object/row of another model'.

Maybe I've missed something basic where one can have it assign a foreignkey to Project_Period from Project_Events without a for loop, which would be ideal.

models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField('Project''s Full Name',max_length=120,blank=False)

class Project_Period(models.Model):
    period_name = models.CharField('Name of reporting period, e.g. Q1 or Semester 2',max_length=120,blank=false)
    period_start = models.DateField('Period Start Date',blank=False)
    period_end = models.DateField('Period Final/End Date',blank=False)

class Project_Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField('Occurence that happened',max_length=120,blank=false)
    event_date = models.DateField('Date event transpired on',blank=False)
    # ..hypothetically it would also have if I could have it assign it automatically based
    # ..on event_date falling within the period_start and period_end dates of Projec_Period
    # ..below code of course won't work as-is:
    # project_period = models.ForeignKey(Project_Period,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Above is just hypothetical sample code, so might have a typo. I've just pruned out a lot of additional fields and further connected models.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Project_Period.objects.filter(period_start__lte=event_date, period_end__gte=event_date)` should give you all possible periods an event can fall in? And then you can set a foreign key to correct period or create a new if none are present?

Comment: that makes sense, but would it need to run through a for-loop, each time setting event_date for the start and end period in that filter? Because every row/object in events needs to compare to that date and have that additional info/foreignkey? That filter on it's own is useful for a view where the user only wants to see events with dates falling in a selected period, but not as-is for setting each event object's individual period and returning all objects.

Comment: Why would you need a loop to set the foreign key of all events (regularly)? Would it not be a one time operation to set the foreign key for all the events (i.e. a data migration). After all events have the foreign key only when the event is updated do you need to set a new one, or when an event is created.

Comment: It would need to be set when the specific Period_Event object is created/updated, or the Period_Event is modified. But also how would one set the foreignkey for the event to the period as an automated calculation, rather than a user-chosen field, given it's a range of dates rather than one set value? Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: 1) I would assume that the periods won't intersect and simply use the first matching period (simplest for this would be to override save method). OR 2) I would make an ajax request the moment user selects an event date and find out matching periods and present them to user to select appropriate one (disallow form submission if none matches).

Comment: Yeah, don't think I explicitly stated it, but no, the periods shouldn't intersect. That should be enforced on the forms with the Project_Period side. So at the risk of sounding like I'm very new to this (which I am), how would one apply #1 above with save overrides. I know the concept of it, just not how to attach a foreignkey based on a lookup within another range (the dates in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the save method and setting the correct foreign key to `Project_Period` there:

```
class Project_Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField('Occurence that happened',max_length=120,blank=false)
    event_date = models.DateField('Date event transpired on',blank=False)
    project_period = models.ForeignKey(Project_Period,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        event_date = self.event_date
        period = Project_Period.objects.filter(period_start__lte=event_date, period_end__gte=event_date).first()
        if period is None:
            raise ValueError("No matching period exists")
        self.project_period = period
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will cause any saved `Project_Event` to automatically have the foreign key set. There are some caveats though you cannot use `queryset.update()` (`Model.objects._____.update()`) or use `Model.objects.bulk_create` as they do not use the models save method. You will need to specify correct `project_period` yourself (by using same logic / different) when calling those methods.